# Combine rows in CSV file that have specified department number

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

I am trying to combine rows that have dept number that starts with '8' into one owneremail(test@mail.com).

Original:

```
| Employee ID | OwnerEmail      |DepartmentNumber |Costs    
| --------    | --------        | --------        | --------
| fg345       | test@mail.com   |8894             |4654.45
| 78f54       | test2@mail.com  |3453             |4994.15
| hg764       | test3@mail.com  |8892             |6543.20
```

Expectation:

```
| Employee ID | OwnerEmail    |DepartmentNumber |Costs     | 
| --------    | --------      |--------         |--------  |
| fg345       | test@mail.com |8894             |11,197.65 |
| 78f54       | test2@mail.co |3453             |4994.15   |
```

What I have attempted so far:

```
if($_.DepartmentNumber.StartsWith('89')-or $_.DepartmentNumber.StartsWith('9r') -or $_.DepartmentNumber.StartsWith('92') -or $_.DepartmentNumber.StartsWith('hemecor') -or $_.DepartmentNumber.StartsWith('HEMECOR') -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.DepartmentNumber))   {Group-Object}
```

Also, I am open to other similar ways of achieving this.

Comment: Please share your coding attempt

Comment: From the Expectation (output) I see you want to merge from the input `fg345` and `hg764` as one. What is the logic to DeparmentNumber in the output, just the first one? What is the logic for the Costs from the output for the first row (`11,197,65`)?

Comment: `... |Sort-Object {$_.DepartmentNumber[0]} -Unique`

Answer (score 1):

`Group-Object` should be helpful here

```
# Import your csv data 
Import-Csv .\grouping.csv | 
    # Use group-object to separate into different groupings
    Group-Object -Property { 
        # use the property parameter and pass it information on how you would like to group
        # here I've choosen to use the first character of the DepartmentNumber value by index (zero-based index)
        $_.DepartmentNumber[0] 
    } | 
        # do something with each group using ForEach-Object
        # Here I'm creating new objects for each group which contain the following properties
        # basically creating a summary with the sum of the costs
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                EmployeeIDs       = $_.Group.EmployeeID -join ', '
                OwnerEmails       = $_.Group.OwnerEmail -join ', '
                DepartmentNumbers = $_.Group.DepartmentNumber -join ', '
                CostSum           = ($_.Group.Costs | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
            }
        }
```

Output

```
EmployeeIDs  OwnerEmails                   DepartmentNumbers  CostSum
-----------  -----------                   -----------------  -------
78f54        test2@mail.com                3453               4994.15
fg345, hg764 test@mail.com, test3@mail.com 8894, 8892        11197.65
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create something like "if value is equal or higher 8000, then add to the list, maybe using the command .append(variable)"  , like this example:

value = 8001

list=[8446,8654,8123,8999]

if value => 8000:
list.append(value)

But consider that my example was in python language, so the append command may not work in other languages

Comment: If your answer doesn't address the topic in question and is not related to the language, it's best to delete the answer. As a new contributor to StackOverflow you can't comment. Please don't abuse the answer as a place to comment.

Comment: I can comment, the site allows me to, so YOU, can't say what I can do.